# The measure of boundary

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $U$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb R^n$, then is it necessarily that $\partial U$, the boundary of $U$, is a set of measure $0$ with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52952/weak-regularity-conditions-for-regions-to-assure-boundary-of-measure-zero

Comment: An equivalent question: [Comparing the Lebesgue measure of an open set and its closure](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28052)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not even in one dimension.  Let $E$ be a [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), which is a closed, nowhere dense subset of $[0,1]$ with positive Lebesgue measure.  (Indeed, its measure can be arbitrarily close to 1.) If we take $U = [0,1] \setminus E$ then $U$ is bounded and open, yet we have $\partial U = E$ which has positive measure.